# How to init a sealed-class in MutableStateFlow

Tags: android, kotlin-flow, kotlin-stateflow, sealed-class

I have a sealed-class like this

```
sealed class LoadState {
    class Loading : LoadState()
    class Success : LoadState()
    class Fail : LoadState()
}
```

I use sealed-class with LiveData, it works

```
open class BaseViewModel: ViewModel() {
//    val loadState by lazy {
//        MutableLiveData<LoadState>()
//    }
    val loadState by lazy {
        MutableStateFlow(LoadState())
    }
}
```

but when I change MutableLiveData to MutableStateFlow, I get a warning like this

```
Sealed types cannot be instantiated
```

so, how to use sealed-class in MutableStateFlow?

Answer (score 8):

You need to specify the type and initial state, like this:

```
val loadState = MutableStateFlow<LoadState>(LoadState.Loading)
```

Answer (score 3):

For using MutableStateFlow with sealed class , you can do something like this :
Step 1 : Create a sealed class .

```
sealed class LoadState {
    object Loading : LoadState()
    object Success : LoadState()
    object Fail : LoadState()
}
```

And then use them in the following way

```
    private val mutableStateFlow : MutableStateFlow<LoadState?> = MutableStateFlow(null)
    val stateFlow : StateFlow<LoadState?> get() = mutableStateFlow
```

You can listen to the mutableStateFlow in the following way. In the OnViewCreated of your fragment :

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {

                viewModel.stateFlow.collect { viewState ->
                    when (viewState) {
                       is Loading ->{//do something}

                       is Success ->{//do something}

                       is Fail->{//do something}
                       
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

In this way you do not need to specify an initial method everytime . This is how you can use sealed class with mutableState Flow

Answer (score 1):

Just write your sealed class name as a stateFlow value type, example:

```
val state = MutableStateFlow<SealedClassName>(SealedClassName.AnySubclassOrObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose your `initial state`

```
open class BaseViewModel: ViewModel() {
    val loadState by lazy {
        MutableStateFlow(LoadState.Loading()) <-- for example, initial is loading
    }
}
```

and also, use `data class` inside sealed class.

```
sealed class LoadState {
    data class Loading() : LoadState()
    data class Success() : LoadState()
    data class Fail() : LoadState()
}
```

Comment: If I initial like this , when I write this code
```
loadState.value = LoadState.Fail()
```
I also got a warning 
```
Type mismatch.
Required: LoadState.Loading
Found: LoadState.Fail
```

Comment: I think u can change the class inside sealed class into `data class`. Maybe can solve your problem

Comment: I change to data class, but it doesn't work, I alos got the waring like this
`Type mismatch. 
Required: LoadState.Loading 
Found: LoadState.Fail `